# mysql text cell containing pounds and ounces

Tags: mysql, text, match

I have a column of data that looks like this and would like to know if there was a way that I could some how extract the pounds and ounces to show the exact weight of the item with in a cell so that I can use it for shipping costs.

To remind you all that I am some what new to this and this one has me stumped.  I don't even know where to begin.

```
Weight varchar (255)

6 lbs. 8 oz.
6 lbs. 8 oz.
6 lbs. 14 oz.
6 lbs. 12 oz.
6 lbs. 12 oz.
7 lbs.
7 lbs.
```

Answer (score 2):

so You have to locate string, that is in the middle (lbs.) i used for that `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` to separete lbs from oz.. [MYSQL DOCUMNETATION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)

```
SELECT 'STR' org,
TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(TRIM('STR'), 'lbs.', 1)) lbs,
TRIM(REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(TRIM('STR'), 'lbs.', -1),'oz.','') oz
from TBL;
```

Aditional You have to use `trim` (for cuting space) and `replace` to get rid of ocz units.

Comment: Perhaps some explanation as to why and how this works would help the OP better understand.